# React Native internal error

Tags: android, react-native

I have been trying to make a simple test app using react native but I am getting this

[image]

Sometimes the app runs without any error but again after sometime this error pops up so cam someone please help me. Thank You!!

This is my console output:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKzoA.png)

And this is what I am getting in android studio logcat:

```
12-04 18:19:42.856 4147-4163/com.album E/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to download JS bundle
                                                          com.facebook.react.common.DebugServerException: The development server returned response error code: 500

                                                          URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

                                                          Body:
                                                          {"type":"InternalError","errors":[],"message":"Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader.processBundleResult(BundleDownloader.java:225)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader.access$100(BundleDownloader.java:40)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader$1.onResponse(BundleDownloader.java:192)
                                                              at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-04 18:19:42.899 4147-4164/com.album E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb407eec0
12-04 18:19:42.902 4147-4147/com.album E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
                                                          com.facebook.react.common.DebugServerException: The development server returned response error code: 500

                                                          URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

                                                          Body:
                                                          {"type":"InternalError","errors":[],"message":"Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader.processBundleResult(BundleDownloader.java:225)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader.access$100(BundleDownloader.java:40)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.BundleDownloader$1.onResponse(BundleDownloader.java:192)
                                                              at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
                                                              at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: We will need to see what the console output is and also what the output on your command line is.

Comment: The error says it’s unable to download js bundle. Thus ensure your application has internet permission or you have internet access

Answer (score 5):

I restarted my laptop and it worked for me.

I am not saying this is the correct solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this error can occur because the application cache needs to be cleaned.

You could try to get into the **Android folder** in the react-native project directory and run this command:`gradlew clean` then go back to react-native root folder and try to run android emulator `react-native run-android`. Also you could try `react-native start --reset-cache`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this line of code in your terminal

1. sudo lsof -i :8081
2. kill -9

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
1.sudo lsof -i :<Your port>
2.Run sudo kill -9 <PID>
3.Run application again
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me
run this command at your project's directory folder

```
expo r -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Fam,
I fixed my issue and like most of them, it's completely my fault. I was refactoring and deleted some files without cleaning up some imports of the deleted files. The only way I found this was to add a console.log in metro (node_modules/metro/src/lib/formatBundlingError.js).

`function formatBundlingError(error) { console.log(error); }`

Answer (score 0):

i refer [here](http://http:/https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15534) and manage to fix this problem

1. downgrade babel-preset-react-native to version 1.9.2
2. run yarn

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you're using `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/` and not `10.0.2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error I solved this error by running `sudo npm i` command inside the project.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get into the Android folder in the react-native project directory and run this command:gradlew clean then go back to react-native root folder and try to run android emulator react-native run-android. Also you could try **react-native start --reset-cache**

Answer (score 0):

It's working

Sometimes this error can occur because the application cache needs to be cleaned.

You could try to get into the Android folder in the react-native project directory and run this command:
`gradlew clean` 
then go back to react-native root folder and try to run android emulator react-native run-android. Also you could try this:
 `react-native start --reset-cache`

Answer (score -1):

React Native 0.59 by default supports version 3 of gradle.  If you have upgraded to version 4 or higher you will get this error:

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**3.3.1'**

When you open the project in Android Studio, if it shows a dialog of Auto Update gradle, you need to skip the update.